# Reformat JS callback to async/await using 3rd party library failed

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am using a 3rd party library ml5 that has a function that returns a callback function. Using Pattern 1 works fine but Pattern 2 failed with error "pixels passed to tf.fromPixels() cannot be null".

I like to use the async / await pattern so that my code is more easily readable. Anyone knows how to achieve make the code works with async/await

**Pattern 1**

```
handleDetect = async snap => {
  const yolo = await ml5.YOLO(snap);

  yolo.detect(function(err, results) {
    console.log(results); 
  });
};
```

**Pattern 2**

```
handleDetect = async snap => {
  const yolo = await ml5.YOLO(snap);

  try {
    const results = await yolo.detect();
    console.log(results);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong with this piece of code given that the documentation says `yolo.detect()` returns a Promise if no callback is provided. I'm curious though -- what if you `console.log(err)` in Pattern 1? Does your code output errors there?

Comment: @therobinkim, thanks. if i include in console.log(err), it still works fine     // Detect objects in the video element
    yolo.detect(function(err, results) {
      if (results) {
        console.log(results);
      } else {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });